# VirtualAlloc Confusions - Is it only for pages?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

I need to use VirtualAlloc to allocate executable memory for my project to JIT re-compile a custom script format to x86/etc. but I feel confused where everyone else seems oblivious and there seems to be a distinct lack of detail in it's behaviour.

I understand that it allocates 'virtual' memory meaning it could be anything physically (RAM/disk), but on use it can simply be considered 'memory'. But if, for example, I do something like:

```
#define MB 1024*1024
auto pAddr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 8*MB, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
VirtualAlloc(pAddr + 4*MB, 1*MB, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);  // commit 1MB, 4MB's into the reserved memory
```

Is that just 1MB used, or 5MB? Obviously, I'm not expecting it to be 5MB - I'm just given no clue what to expect in this seemingly obvious scenario. Is it valid? Can any range within the reserved memory be committed and de-committed freely? What's more, can it be used out-of-order or should it be allocated incrementally (which going by MSDN documentation, is all it looks like you can do with it). Or is VirtualAlloc only happy with 'pages' being allocated at a time?

Every example I have found only seems interested in showing me how to allocate pages - which is probably just the most basic use possible but far from the most practical - but I want to use this for allocating compiled code for scripts which may be re-compiled during execution occasionally. I need to try and make some sort of interface for these allocations so I can simply say "gimme some memory for this script compilation" and it will automatically return previously committed space that isn't used or commit some new space - so any tips on how best to allocate from virtual memory (e.g. is it best to not de-commit memory which may likely be committed again?) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Once you have reserved a region, you may commit and decommit individual pages within that region in any order. Only committed pages count toward memory usage. If you tell me where in MSDN it says that all committed pages must be contiguous, I can fix it. (Each VirtualAlloc calls commits a contiguous range of page, but you can call it two times with ranges that are not adjacent.)

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are asking.  There are two distinct ways to allocate memory in a process, VirtualAlloc() is the low-level one, HeapAlloc() is the high-level one.  HeapAlloc() does a lot more, you can easily ask for arbitrary sizes and release them again.  Not VirtualAlloc(), sizes you can get are a multiple of 64KB and it is entirely up to you to carve it up.  You must use the low-level one, only way to control the page protection flags.

Comment: @CheersAndHthAlf
you removed the 'virtual-machine' tag from my question (when the question itself is clearly for the purpose of a virtual machine) but added 'windows' (when the code could easily be written without the Windows API using mmap - though you didn't even add the tag "windows-api" but "windows" which is an OS). Is this for a logical reason (and please take your time answering that) or could you just not resist meddling with something?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, VirtualAlloc is the only one I am asking about. I never mentioned HeapAlloc, but I do pretty much want to make my own heap-like allocation methods - but knowing what this does on a lower level seems critical for using it for any non-basic use through VirtualAlloc.

Comment: @RaymondChen Understood, but MSDN is unclear about contiguity at all - the most revealing thing I could find was the code example of allocating pages, which are not only allocated contiguously but also with fixed-sizes - I wouldn't mind doing that and then distributing that memory from my higher-level interface into smaller chunks, but I just need to know for sure if I have to. And so if I VirtualAlloc'd two regions with a gap between, they would only really be allocating one solid block of actual memory, I guess? I could even wrecklessly leave small gaps between large allocs with no issues?

Comment: @Deji: `VirtualAlloc` is a Windows API function. Yes there are similar functions for other OSes. If you want information about such other functions, then the question should include that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unclear about contiguity". It makes no mention of contiguity. It just says that the function operates on a region of pages. The samples are intentionally simplified and do not exercise the full range of the API.

Comment: Exactly. I guess my phrasing was off. It's WORSE than unclear about it - by not mentioning it at all. I looked through all the sections in the hopes of finding some more technical information or some more colourful examples, then looked at any random code samples Google could find and finally I resorted to asking here. MSDN's brevity is a real-time waster (yes, that misplaced dash is a pun).

Comment: It says that it allocates a range of pages. If you call it twice, you can allocate two ranges of pages. (Clearly it is possible for the two ranges to be discontiguous - after all, not all the memory in your process is jammed together in one contiguous block.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK; I *think* I understand what you're getting at and I hope this will clarify things.

Conceptually, VirtualAlloc works on individual pages.

For simplicity, let's consider a 32-bit x86 process.  The virtual address space is a sequence of pages from page 0 through to page 1048575.  Each of these pages may or may not be reserved; if reserved, it may or may not be committed.  (If committed, it will also have zero or more memory-protection options, and there are various other states a page might be in, but we can pretty much ignore all that for now.)

There is no way for only part of a page to be reserved or committed, or for two parts of the same page to have different memory-protection options.  Conversely, it doesn't matter whether the reserved and/or committed pages are consecutive.

If you call VirtualAlloc with a particular starting address and region size, then it acts on every page containing one or more bytes within the virtual address region specified.  The address and size are used *only* to calculate which pages to act on.  The only reason that the argument is an address rather than a page number is to simplify things for the programmer.

Conceptually, a single call to VirtualAlloc covering multiple pages is equivalent to calling VirtualAlloc once for each of those pages.  The only difference (other than efficiency) is that acting on multiple pages at once is atomic, so will either fail or succeed for the entire range.

Note in particular that if you successfully make multiple calls to VirtualAlloc covering consecutive pages, there is no way to tell afterwords that the pages were allocated separately.  The operating system only remembers what state a page is in, not how it got there.  [***Addendum:*** Oops; this is wrong.  The documentation for [`VirtualQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it can tell whether consecutive pages were part of the same allocation or not.  Perhaps they're tagged with a unique allocation ID or something.  I don't believe this information is actually used by the memory manager at all, but apparently it *is* kept.]

Keep in mind that the HeapCreate function already allows you to create a heap whose memory blocks allow code execution.  Unless your application has very unusual needs it is unlikely that you will gain anything by writing your own heap manager.

Comment: Actually, my application is indeed unusual (as are most things involving the use of just-in-time compilation) - and VirtualAlloc is favored for relativity to mmap so they're already both solidly implemented in wrappers for easy targeting of multiple platforms. Only reason this question is arising now is because I've never had to do such finicky memory management before, but since ambitions are high, I'm aiming for something a lot more efficient. I understand HeapCreate doesn't allow reservation while not consuming physical storage. Anyway, you've cleared this up for me entirely now, thanks!

Comment: @Deji: Glad this helped.  For future reference, you should note that I would never have seen this question if Alf hadn't retagged it as "windows".

Comment: The operating system does keep track of `VirtualAlloc` that span multiple pages so that it knows how much to free when you call `VirtualFree`. `VirtualAlloc` is a bit overloaded in that it is used both to allocate regions and pages within that region. (This is done as a simplification for users who are interested only in managing regions and not in page-by-page fine-tuning of pages within the region.)

Answer (score 3):

It's pages only.

The history of `VirtualAlloc` (a Windows API function) and its concept of memory pages is tied to the evolution of the Intel x86 processor family.

With the original 8086 processor (cirka 1979 IIRC, with the first PC based on it in 1980?) addressing at the machine code level was 16-bit. By itself that would have yielded a maximum 64K address range, but the processor treated each address as only an **offset** into a 64K **segment** of memory. It supported four logical segment, namely code, data, stack and an "extra" segment, and which of these an address was an offset into depended on the context. The start of each segment in physical memory was determined by 16-bit **segment selector** registers, called respectively CS, DS, SS and ES. To form the start address of a segment the processor simply shifted the selector 4 bits to the left, corresponding to a multiplication by 16. Thus the **physical address* corresponding to an offset O used in a context where the segment selector was S, was A = 16*S + O, which made for roughly 20-bit physical addresses (but you could wrap around a little at the top).

logical address = (segment offset, segment selector)
        calculation( offset, selector ) → physical address

With the 80286 the segment selectors were mapped to physical addresses via tables, which allowed for much more memory, and allowed segments of different sizes. I think it had 24-bit physical addresses, not sure; it was still an essentially 16-bit processor, but supporting (relatively speaking) lots of memory. With the 286 it made sense to talk about the offsets as **logical addresses**, because a process couldn't just calculate the corresponding physical address.

logical address = (segment offset, segment selector)
        lookup( offset, selector ) → physical address

The 80386 finally brought 32-bit programming to the PC. A code segment could be 32-bit or 16-bit, determining the interpretation of the machine code there. Moreover it supported transparent automatic **memory management**, with virtual memory (simulating real memory by using disk storage). To do that it added another layer of address translation, based on fixed size **pages**. So a program's logical address was first treated as a segment offset, 286-style, and the resulting middle-level address was then decomposed into a memory page selector plus page offset, with each memory page of fixed size. The idea being that fixed size pages could be efficiently swapped to disk, and back.

logical address = (segment offset, segment selector)
        lookup( soffset, sselector ) → intermediate address

intermediate address = (page offset, page selector)
        lookup( poffset, pselector ) → physical address or "page not mapped"

For this to be meaningful you need to have far more possible logical pages than there are pages of physical memory. For if not then every logical page could just be mapped to its own physical page, and swapping would have no benefit. And this means that committing logical pages, i.e. mapping them to physical pages, can fail.

These are the pages handled by `VirtualAlloc` and family. You can allocate logical pages. And you map them to physical pages by committing, which, due to the purpose of the whole scheme, can necessarily be done on single pages: a page is the *unit of memory management* at the hardware level.

Comment: Well it makes for nice answer-roundedness, but I do happen to know as much as I need (possibly more) to know about the history of the x86 processor family. However you have steered my mind in another direction with this answer by saying it's for pages when I was starting to think the answer was it certainly wasn't. Unless you mean that it handles it in pages, but I won't necessarily need to worry about that when using VirtualAlloc (otherwise, surely it would take params to allocate (n) pages instead of needing a specific size where the page size has to be looked up by OS-specific functions)?

Comment: On Windows x86/64 the page size is usually 4K - so surely if VirtualAlloc is for pages, I should only allocate multiples of that? It's strange as I've definitely seen VirtualAlloc being used as flexibly as I want, but this still doesn't tell me if there's anything wrong with the code I posted, for example.

Comment: @Deji: yes, preferably you should allocate only on page boundaries and only in multiples of the page size.  However, if you choose to ignore this, VirtualAlloc will simply over-allocate as necessary.  I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, but more than that, I don't understand what made you think that there might be anything wrong with it.

Comment: Well that's just it, I'm making my own memory-management interface to handle this so I need to be sure what's happening on a low level. If it's over-allocating, I might as well make my class do the over-allocation calculation and have it knowing exactly how much is available in that region for later re-purposing. Anyway, this clears a lot up and is actually easier to think about than what I thought might be the case (but not as cool, heh).